# How to check with multiple substrings to get the column names in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in python pandas I pulling the columns based on the below condition

```
spike_cols = [col for col in nodes.columns if 'Num' in col]
print(spike_cols)
```

But I am looking for multiple substrings to check in the columns if exist I want to pull all the columns that match any one of the substring

```
spike_cols = [col for col in nodes.columns if ('Num'|'Lice') in col]
    print(spike_cols)
```

But I am getting below error

```
: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for this in combination with `regex` argument:

```
# Create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'HelloNum': [1,2],
                  'World':[3,4],
                  'This':[5,6],
                  'ExampleLice':[7,8]})

print(df)

   HelloNum  World  This  ExampleLice
0         1      3     5            7
1         2      4     6            8
```

Apply `DataFrame.filter`

```
print(df.filter(regex='Num|Lice'))
   HelloNum  ExampleLice
0         1            7
1         2            8
```

Get column names in list

```
df.filter(regex='Num|Lice').columns.tolist()

['HelloNum', 'ExampleLice']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'Num|Lice')]]
```

If all you want is the column names themselves:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'Num|Lice')].tolist()
```

Comment: this is giving me the entire filtered data frame But I need just columns

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
spike_cols = [col for col in nodes.columns if ('Num' in col or 'Lice' in col)]
```